# My while validation loop is not accepting valid answer and breaking, automatically moving to else statement

Tags: python

```
    # this is a simple calculator
import sys


def calculation():
    print('what is the first number?')
    x = int(input())
    print('what is the second number?')
    y = int(input())
    # these two lines ask for the two numbers
    print('would you like to do multiplication, division, addition, or subtraction?')
    # the following loop makes the user choose which operator they wish to use
    while True:
        input_a = input()
        if input_a == 'multiplication' or input_a == 'division' or input_a == 'addition' or input_a == 'subtraction':
            break
        else:
            print('please choose a valid option')
    if input_a == 'multiplication':  # the multiplication calculation
        print(str(x) + ' multiplied by ' + str(y) + ' is equal to:')

        def multiply():
            return x*y

        print(multiply())
    elif input_a == 'division':
        print(str(x) + ' divided by ' + str(y) + ' is equal to:')

        def divide():
            try:
                return x/y
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print('you cannot divide by zero')

        print(divide())


print(calculation())
while True:  #this loop repeats the program
    calculation()
    print('would you like to repeat? y/n')
    input_b = input()
    if input_b == 'n':
        sys.exit()
```

im not quite sure why, but in my while validation loop, even if one gives a valid answer, it still does not break

allow me to apologize beforehand, but i have only been coding python for about 3 days now, so if my code could have been better optimized by using a different method, thats why i didnt do it

for some reason however, it started working correctly when i didnt define the whole program as a function, however i did that to make it easier to give the option to re-start the program by user choice

Edit: so i found the issue, and it was because i was trying an input i didnt actually code yet, thanks for reminding me to check for errors on my side

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some sample input. This code is working fine for me for several inputs I tried.

Comment: It is also working for me. What is an example of an input that causes a problem for you?

Comment: This code is working for me. Can you give a simple input? There's a possibility you had a typo when testing inputs out

Comment: to avoid any typo change `if input_a == 'multiplication' or input_a == 'division' or input_a == 'addition' or input_a == 'subtraction':` to `if input_a == '*' or input_a == '/' or input_a == '+' or input_a == '-':` and test by input operators after making the other necessary modification, your code is good as a lunching point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,whatever you are doing is complicated so here is the simple version of it:

```
def add(x,y):   
    return(x+y)
def sub(x,y):   
    return(x-y)
def mult(x,y):  
    return(x*y)
def div(x,y):
    return(x/y)

while True:
    x=int(input('First No.: '))
    y=int(input('First No.: '))

    method=input('Operator: ')#will call a specific function from the dictionary
    functs={'add':add(x,y),'subtract':sub(x,y),'multiply':mult(x,y),'divide':div(x,y)}

    print(functs[method.lower()])#print the required result

    choice=input('Continue? Y/N: ')
    if choice=='N':
        break
print('Loop Break')
```